# How to configure n98 mage run for xdebug?

Tags: xdebug

Xdebug for magento generally works, but there are problems with magerun, instead of debugging the cron class, debug n98-magerun2.phar occurs. I tried to configure path mapping, but it still debugs n98-mage run 2.phar. How can this be fixed?

Comment: which IDE? php storm?

Comment: Now i use PHPStorm

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me more about this. Because as per my knowledge,X-debug uses for the debugging and n98-mage run for the DB related things . Then I will help you more regarding this.

Comment: I want to debug the cron class of the task, through magerun I run the cron task once, in PHPStorm I listen to the magerun port, debugging begins, but for some reason the magerun2.phar file is debugged instead of the cron class of the task.